# Import enum values declared in same file in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

How to to import enums that are declared in the same file into the current scope? So it could be used without type specification? [playground](https://pl.kotl.in/MeN5zViui)

```
enum class E1 { a, b }

fun main() {
    val e: E1 = a // I want to use just a, not E1.a 
    println(e)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can import your class to the same file:

```kotlin
import E1.*

enum class E1 { a, b }

fun main() {
    val e: E1 = a
    println(e)
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me.